# Numpy interp not interpolating/extrapolating the values, only finding if the data point is above or below the max empirical value

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following empirical data:

```
emp_data = np.array([[0.5, -24.111869188789498],
[1.0, -30.166986253668671],
[1.5, -33.310250723584765],
[2.0, -35.629672538473848],
[2.5, -39.416821042883605],
[3.0, -41.05367278405226],
[3.5, -42.702793174115918],
[3.653, -41.173808136289971],
[4.0, -45.327195234249011],
[4.5, -47.170664776211105],
[5.0, -45.838914309065679],
[5.5, -47.83778613822286],
[6.0, -49.55982614930786],
[6.5, -48.899619370977753]])
```

And I want to interpolate or extrapolate a value from this data based on a new data point similar to the second column. eg -38. If I try interpolate this value interp returns 6.5.

```
numpy.interp(-38, emp_data[:,1], emp_data[:,0])
Out[65]: 6.5
```

numpy interp returns 6.5 for any value below -48.89 (the max value in the emprical data) and 0.5 for any value above. Anyone know why?

thanks

Comment: the docs mention that the `xp` values must be increasing. Have tried sorting the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the help of `numpy.interp`

> Does not check that the x-coordinate sequence `xp` is increasing. If
>   `xp` is not increasing, the results are nonsense. A simple check for
>   increasingness is::
>
> ```
> np.all(np.diff(xp) > 0)
> ```

It looks like you have mixed up abscissae, i.e. x-values, and ordinates, i.e. f(x) or y-values.

So, if you want to find the x-value, where `f(x)=-38`, in an automated fashion, you need something more than just interpolation. For example, you may fit a polynomial `p(x)` to your data and then look for the roots of `p(x)-(-38)`.

Comment: Looks like you're right, I've ordered xp and it interpolates within the data but can't extrapolate outside of the range of xp. do you jnow of any simple ways to fit a polynomial to the data (eg another numpy function?)

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to reverse x and y, as you do by sorting and interpolating, since this is only well posed if your function is injective, i.e. increasing (or decreasing).

Comment: There is `numpy.polyfit` to find the interpolant. You should use it for finding the roots. However, extrapolating leads to large errors.

Comment: I don't need this to be hugely accurate - just give me a general ballpark figure really so that would probably work.

Comment: So if I find the polynomial I want to find the value of p where p(x) = -38 (or whatever value I'm trying to extrapolate?

Comment: Okok. Use this p(x) for INTER-polation. Don't take a high degree, since this will lead oscillations. Maybe `deg=3` will do. But check your data. DON'T use `p` outside your data. I don't have a picture readily available, but you may leave out the outer point and see how well (or bad) it is interpolated by `p`.

Comment: For extrapolation better use regression. see http://glowingpython.blogspot.de/2012/03/linear-regression-with-numpy.html